# Web Service as push notification?

Tags: android, service, notifications, web, push

I'm quite new to the server-client design
now I'm using web service to communicate between Android and Java server and suddenly come up with a weird idea...
if I implement a webservice that doesn't response until any update is detected on the server (and the update is the response), will the trick works on:
 1. using a thread to call the service during the activity to provide any update
 2. using service to call the service after the activity so any update is "pushed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid that will not work. Most likely your request will simply timeout before the response is returned.

To do push messaging from the server to an Android client, check out Google's [Cloud To Device Messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) framework.

Comment: I'm aware of the C2DM, but as I need the app to be compatible with Kindle Fire too, I'm finding other potential alternative.... having my eyes on Urban Airship or Xtify but they're quite pricey.

Comment: The other option of course is polling. i.e. You simply have your Android app periodically request any updates from the server via a lightweight call. This is the really the only way to do this sort of thing reliably if you're not going to go the whole hog with a full push messaging framework.